# AudioQueueNewInput decreases playback volume for AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone

I am using Stephen Celis' SCListener class to record iPhone microphone audio levels.  I also am playing audio through the use of AVAudioPlayer.  For example, the user presses 'Play' to kick off a sound playing in the background and then has the option to blow into the microphone to play additional, shorter sounds.  The code all works fine, playing all the sounds when they should be played, however, the AVAudioPlayer sound volume *greatly* decreases when you begin listening with the SCListener.  I have narrowed down the culprit to this line in the SCListener source code:

AudioQueueNewInput(&format, listeningCallback, self, NULL, NULL, 0, &queue);

I have racked my brain and can not find out how to keep the playback volume at it's highest level once this line has executed.  I have spoken with Stephen Celis, too, and he does not know what is happening.  It is possible, I suppose, that the iPhone turns down the output volume when the microphone is being used so that feedback isn't introduced, but it seems like there should be a way to disable that.

In summary:

1. Start playing long audio file with AVAudioPlayer - 100% volume (loud).
2. Enable SCListener and begin listening (which calls AudioQueueNewInput).
3. The output volume on the AVAudioPlayer sound greatly decreases
4. Call [[SCListener sharedListener] stop] to dispose of the queue
5. AVAudioPlayer sound resumes higher playback volume

Has anyone seen anything like this or have any ideas on how to keep the playback volume higher?  I have explicitly set the volume parameter to 1.0f to ensure that the gain is at it's highest level.

Comment: Found this possible solution on the apple developer forums: By default apples Audio Session settings reroute playback audio to the headphone socket only (disables speakers output) when recording from the microphone at the same time. You have to enable the speaker output via session properties to get output to the speakers while recording.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Stephen Celis's work, but if tposchel's suggestion does not work, it might be of some value to look at the InputQueue's values versus the OutputQueue's audio values in debug mode (this is tricky, though, since the callbacks for these methods are realtime threads).

This may be informative in that it will tell you what the OS believes it is sending to your output device (headphone, or built-in speaker).

The brute force way to fix this problem is to manually normalize (or scale up, as it were) the values within your OutputQueue's callback.  This doesn't address your root problem, perhaps, but may be a hack until you find the answer.